# Deployment of managed Package with Analytics fails because of Integration User Permissions

Tags: managed-package, einstein-analytics, analytics

Dear Stackexchange Community,

We´ve created a managed package witch contains several Analytics components.
When we try to install it on a "Salesforce Analytics Development Org" or any Scratch Org with Analytics enabled we get some errors which I´m unable to fix.

The main Problem seems to be:

It says that several fields in our node "sfdcDigest_[PACKAGENAME]__Skill__c" for example:
[PACKAGENAME]__Skill__c
[PACKAGENAME]__Score__c
...

Aren´t either available or the Integration user don´t have the required permissions.
At this point im not sure how to grant the missing permissions to the integration user.
In our packaging Org the Integration user have the right "View All Data" and all Dataflows run without any problems.

Error-Message: (translated from German)
In the 'sfdcDigest_[PACKAGENAME]__Skill' node, the '[PACKAGENAME]__Skill__c'  field doesn't exist or isn't accessible to the Integration User.

This error seems strange to me. The Integration User should be allowed to see the Fields.

To summarize:
The Package delivers the Objects itself and the Analytics part. Is this the problem? is this some kind of order issue, that the analytics part is installed first before the object itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The salesforce support finally managed to answer: During Installation you have to deactivate the Integration User and the synchronisation. After installation reactivate everything again.